# Django - display html with css without staticfiles

Tags: html, css, django

Currently learning basics of Django. I kind of understand the concept of url and views. I've downloaded a bootstrap template and I wanted to set it as main page. I know, that I could redo all the page, making it template and put `css` files into static folder, then link it with `url` and it should probably work. I managed to display the page creating a lambda HttpResponse function, but I am unable to link css there. Is such thing possible? Can I somehow drop a webpage with css into folder and link it, or do I have to do it django way?
I know, that django way is less messy and probably better, but this is for test and learning purposes only.
Sorry, if it was already asked, I tried looking for the answer before asking.

Answer (score 0):

Copy your css, and put it in HTML page inside `<style> </style>` tag.

Comment: Can't it just be linked? It works while displaying html file, why wouldn't it work with django?
I can do it, but it makes the file more messy and also requires me to copy it into all the pages I would want to show.

Comment: Django looks in static files, try changing static file location in settings file

Comment: I know, that it does but I just wanted it to output this html page as is, just like browser does. Simple copy paste into the project and linking it in `urls.py`

Comment: Then just don't use django, put HTML and CSS files in same directory, link CSS into html, and type html path in URL bar

Comment: Ok, more details. I just wanted to set ip:port/ to some template page downloaded from the internet. There is also the rest of the app, that does some stuff.

Comment: Hope you understand the serving application through application server and just loading html page into browser

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113843/discussion-between-fulaphex-and-kishor-pawar).

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're going that route because it seems complex to get the static file serving working.  Serving your static files is something that's really easy to do - and once you've pointed your static file at something, you can just use if for testing anything:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = ("/Users/you/path/to/static",)
```

Then you just need to use static in the url for that page.

Answer (score 0):

I use a `base.html` that is extended by all of my templates. You can either have it `{% include %}` your css, or simply reference it. So you can change 1 variable (I do it in my master [context file](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#template-context-processors)) and have all of your templates go along for the ride. E.g.

In base.html:

```
<html>
<head>
{% if testing %}
    <!-- directly include stylesheet in page -->
    <style>{% include "my.css" %}<style>
{% else %}
    <!-- standard stylesheet link -->
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='my.css'>
{% end %}
</head>
<body>
{% block content %}
{% endblock content %}
</body>
</html>
```

In your templates:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
     Hi, Mom!
{% endblock content %}
```

BTW, a `base.html` that has your full site design and makes *very* liberal use of `{% block %}` can make the majority of your view templates short and sweet. [The template docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/) are your friend!